# Keyword import returns undefiend for bcrypt package

Tags: node.js, import, require, bcrypt, nestjs

I'm writing on basic `Nestjs` starter project and when I `import` bcrypt - it returns `undefined`, but when I use `require('bcrypt')` it returns 
 the bcrypt object.

How to import bcrypt via the `import` keyword?

---

My os is MacOS and I've installed [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) package v `^3.0.0`.
My node version is `10.14.1`;

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Import the anonymous function and give it a name

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
```

---

Alternatively, install the typings for bcrypt.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/bcrypt
```

Then import and use the functions directly

```
import {hash} from 'bcrypt';
```

Comment: `import {hash} from 'bcrypt';` works
But why? That's because there is no export default i guess?

Answer (score 0):

Import is used in typescript, required is used in javascript. To use typescript, you have to install it 
`$ npm install typescript`

You've installed bcrypt, so you know how to install packages, the above line is just for completion

Comment: nestjs has built-in typescript, all project is written on typescript

Comment: @Link sorry I didn't notice nestjs tag